# How to pass spark broadcast and accumulator variables to map and reduce functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider the following code snippet

```
class SparkJob extends Serializable{
//Some code and other functions
def launchJob = {
    val broadcastConfiguration = sc.broadcast(options) //options is some case class
    val accumulator = //create instance of accumulator
    inputFile.mapPartitions(lines => testMap(lines, broadcastConfiguration, accumulator)) //this line will throw a serialization error
}
object SparkJob{
//apply and other functions
def testMap(lines: Iterable[String], broadcastConfiguration: ... //other params) = //function definition
}
```

How do I pass the instance of accumulator and broadcastConfiguration with the other function?

I tries using only `inputFile.mapPartitions(lines => testMap(lines))` and it worked fine so it seemed to me that the shared variables were a problem while passing. How do I accomplish this?

**Edit: Added Exception Trace**

```
15/06/17 19:12:56 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from textFile at SparkJob.scala:74
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:635)
    at com.auditude.databuild.steps.SparkJob.launchJob(SparkJob.scala:80)
    at com.auditude.databuild.steps.SparkJobDriver$.main(SparkJobDriver.scala:37)
    at com.auditude.databuild.steps.SparkJobDriver.main(SparkJobDriver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$ObjectStreamClassMethods$.getObjFieldValues$extension(SerializationDebugger.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.getObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2050)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1252)
    ... 29 more
```

**Edit2:** Added @transient as per suggestion but it did not help. I even tried this approach and still for the same answer.

```
val mapResult = inputFile.mapPartitions(lines =>  {
  println(broadcastConfiguration.value)
  lines
})
```

**Edit 3** - On further investigation I realised that in order to simplify my code for SO I had ommitted the detail that I initialize the broadcastConfiguration in the constructor of my class so the actual code looks like:

```
class SparkJob extends Serializable{
  //constructor
  val broadcastConfiguration = sc.broadcast(options) //options is some case class
  val accumulator = //create instance of accumulator
//Some code and other functions
def launchJob = {
    inputFile.mapPartitions(lines => testMap(lines, broadcastConfiguration, accumulator)) //this line will throw a serialization error
}
```

I tried with a simple string without using broadcastVariable by initializing it in the constructor and it still failed. If I move the declaration of that string into the function launchJob it seems to work atleast for the string. Will report back with a further edit in case even broadcast variables work that way. I still am wondering why this is happening though as my class was declared `Serializable`.

Comment: could you add the exception?

Comment: @maasg Added the stack trace.

Comment: @Sohab your function should use the value of the broadcast object and not the bc itself, but the exception does not relate to that. Weird. Try adding `@transient` to the declaration of the bc and counter.

Comment: I am not using the bc itself. In the function there would be something like `bc.value`. In this case however bc is passed just like there is nothing in the `testMap` except some print lines. I will try the `@transient` but isnt using annotations deprecated?

Comment: `@transient` is the way to indicate when some field should not be serialized. Perfectly OK to use.

Comment: @maasg See the latest edit please.